# Cyclist leaning when rounding a bend

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Why?

Now here's the question that got me pondering

> A  cyclist rounds a bend, The surface of the road is horizontal. The cyclist is forced to lean at an angle of $20^\circ$ to the vertical to 'only just' take the bend successfully. The total sideways frictional force on the tyres is 360 N. The cycle has a mass of 20 kg. What is the mass of the cyclist? (Answer: 78.9 kg)

The trouble I'm having is that I don't understand why the cyclist has to lean to begin with, I tried drawing a free body diagram and equating the torques on the cyclist, but I get 80.9 kg as my answer instead. I also tried resolving the forces like shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/615921/why-does-reaction-force-change-when-a-cyclist-bends), which curiously also got me 80.9 kg.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does tilting a bike make it turn sharper?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/419353/)

Comment: @AlphaLife yes, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g = 9.81\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$. You approximated $g = 10$ when converting masses to weights, so your answer for (mass of cyclist plus mass of bike) is $10/9.81$ of the total mass.

Comment: Hmm it seems like it's the other way around, the answer used the approximation g=10, which does give the answer 78.9. Could you please show your working?